# Ubuntu chrome not saving passwords after deleting keyring

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, browser, keyrings, gnome-keyring

Chrome browser stopped saving passwords locally after I deleted the Keyring file using this command

`rm -i ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring`

Please let me know how to fix this and make chrome save passwords again locally.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can I know why this was downvoted?

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it with

```
sudo rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome
sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable
```

and reinstall with .deb file from web mirror. Manually deleting config files was probably unnecessary.